# Why does reviewers not accept? Reject the edits without understanding

Tags: discussion, answers, review

I had edited an answer, based on my search and experience.
Like this one. [image: screenhot-rejected]

I am not sure if the peer reviewer understood the question, and then my answer. 
If these are the reviewers, then this document : [Stack* based developrs write more vulnerable code than others !](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2017/cmsc818O/papers/get-where-look.pdf) is very much valid !! ??

[Link to the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10351/390742)
[Link to the review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/323152)

Comment: JFC, atleast post a link to the question instead of this horrible screenshot amalgation.

Comment: Consider adding the relevant text as _text_ to your question, or at least crop the screenshots to only cover the relevant bits. I really can't make out much of the text in those screen dumps.

Comment: It is a continuous scrolled images capture. Would you be able to see continuity in the screenshots ? Screenshots are for the reason, if later link is removed !

Comment: Ideally, I'd want to be able to read the text to understand your issue. I currently can't read it because it's small and fuzzy.

Comment: After the edit to original question, added the links  Link to the question Link to the review.  Picture is "zoom"able, makes it in the "actual size" and readable.

Comment: If you see a top comment :  _< Well, this doesn't tell me what caused the shutdown, only when it was done. Which I already know, see my question. – alex Apr 5 '11 at 6:22 >_   which was to the Original Answer [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10351/390742) which I edited, explains what kind of Peer Review was done

Answer (score 9):

I vote to reject your edit for two reasons:

- the first part of your edit doesn’t add any substantive content, it’s a variation on the existing `last -x | less` command and an example;
- the second part of your edit is incorrect: the X server error message doesn’t give any clue regarding the reason of the shutdown.

I’m not saying the post you edited can’t be improved; in particular, the link at the end isn’t useful, and should either be expanded upon or removed IMO. However there are other answers to the question which provide similar information.

Comment: 1. are you sure "edit doesn’t add any substantive content" ? variation on the existing last -x | less command because, existing command does not point to or narrow down what we need to look at. Try it yourself !   2. Are you saying _error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server_   and later _kill_ and  _Stopped User Manager_ does not lead me to clue that X11 is issue ?

Comment: 1. `last -x | less` shows you all the information that `last -x | head | cat` does, and more. 2. Yes, those errors indicate that the X server was shut down, but that happens during normal system shutdown, and wouldn’t cause a system shutdown on its own. You’d need to determine why the X server was shut down, and even then, that wouldn’t explain the system shutdown.

Comment: 1.  As Clearly mentioned "narrow down what we need to look at" Does not it? For me,  ` last -x | less` gives huge list .. Where as the one way I mentioned it does `tac`

Comment: 2. _error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server_ happens during normal shutdown ???? Are you sure ??  :D

Comment: Yes, it happens when the X server stops before all its clients; it’s an error produced by an X client when it can no longer contact the X server. That’s a fairly regular occurrence during typical shutdowns.

Comment: Well , we are not talking about normal shutdowns here ! Question was about crashes. If I know  5 min ago, my Ubuntu crashed. And when reading the logs if I could find only this, and after that there is SIGKILL. .. !! well it tells me. I don't know what other factors made you to reject my edit !

Comment: After my edit, I wonder, why the original answer which was up-voted 121 times, wasn't moderated !!??? It CLEARLY does not answer the Original Question ! :D See the Original Questioner's comment :  _Well, this doesn't tell me what caused the shutdown .... .... alex_

Comment: Your edit doesn’t help answer the question either. You’re analysing the logs with tinted glasses: you know there was a crash, so anything which vaguely looks like a crash jumps out at you. But those logs don’t explain the shutdown, they only show that it happened.

Comment: Well, it was not shutdown, it was XServer crash, looks like shutdown. But kernel was still up. So for user it looks like reboot ! You can call it Tinted Glass, whatever. But _error_  _warning_ are the places where I look at ususally for such scenario :D  I wonder Reviewers also with glasses to selectively reject , and then argue on over :D  No wonder that report on vulnerable codes is near to it

Answer (score 7):

Even if your edit is correct, if it fundamentally changes the answer it should not be an edit but a new answer.

From the [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) on [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/editing) (emphasis mine):

---

Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:

- To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
- To clarify the meaning of the post (**without changing that meaning**)
- To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
- To correct **minor** mistakes or add updates as the post ages
- To add related resources or hyperlinks

Comment: If it has to be a new answer , rejected reason should have been _it should be a new answer, not edit_. Not as by the reviewers _doesn’t add any substantive content_

Comment: As it says .. _add related resources_  .. My answer does not change the meaning. As the Original Question posted himself commented, the Original Answer in itself, does not answer his question :D  See his comment _Well, this doesn't tell me what caused the shutdown .... .... alex_